# Is there a way to view blobs of managed disks in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer or the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azureportal, azure-managed-disk

When I create a VM using Azure Resource Manager with an **unmanaged** disk, I can view its .vhd in [Microsft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) and/or the Azure Portal under the specified storage account's Blob Container in a sub-container called "vhds".

When I create a VM using Azure Resource Manager with a **managed** disk, I can't find any storage container with anything related to this managed disk.

I understand that Azure is "managing" this storage for me, per [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-managed-disks-overview), and also that I can generate a "SAS Url" for this disk (which gives me no real info on where the blob is stored), but I believe (let me know if I'm wrong), that Azure must be storing my "managed disk" in a storage account within my subscription, and that I should be able to see the blobs for these "managed disks" somewhere in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer or in the Azure Portal.

Is there an easy way to view these managed disk .vhds in either the portal or Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now, it is not possible to view managed disk .vhds on Portal or Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

Managed disk is different from unmanaged disk, managed disks are stored in a Microsoft managed storage account. For now, we could not view it. You could copy managed disks to your private storage account.

```
##create $SAS
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName shui -DiskName shuitest -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read 
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName contosostorageav1 -StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageAccountKey' 
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer 'vhds' -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob 'MyDestinationBlobName.vhd'
```

Notes:

If the managed disk attach to a VM, you should stop your VM, then you could copy it to your storage account.