# Download Azure VHD to local use powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, vhd

How can I download azure vhd with powershell to local machine?

I read the document, but I can't find the blob url like "https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/XXX.vhd"

Anybody know that?

Thanks

Comment: Your VM uses managed disk? You could check it on Azure Portal, on your VM resource group, you could find a disk resource.

Comment: If you use managed disk, you could not see the vhd file in your storage account. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, your VM uses managed disk not unmanaged disk. So, you could not find the VHD file in storage account. More information about managed disk please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/faq-for-disks).

If you want to download the VHD in managed disk, you should copy it to a storage account first.

```
##create $SAS
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName shui -DiskName shuitest -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read 
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName contosostorageav1 -StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageAccountKey' 
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer 'vhds' -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob 'MyDestinationBlobName.vhd'
```

Then, you could use [`Save-AzureVhd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/save-azurevhd?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) or [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to download the VHD to your local.

Please refer to the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915605/is-there-a-way-to-view-blobs-of-managed-disks-in-microsoft-azure-storage-explore).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Save-AzureVhd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/save-azurevhd?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) cmdlet to download the vhd file to local machine.

> The Save-AzureVhd cmdlet enables download of .vhd images from a blob
> where they are stored to a file. It has parameters to configure the
> download process by specifying the number of downloader threads that
> are used or overwriting the file which already exists in the specified
> file path.
>
> Save-AzureVhd does not do any VHD format conversion and the blob is downloaded as it is.

Example PowerShell cmdlets:

```
Save-AzureVhd -Source "http://YourStorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/yourContainerName/win7baseimage.vhd" -LocalFilePath "C:\vhd\Win7Image.vhd"
```

To get the exact URL, Login to Azure Portal, Select Storage Account and the vhd file, then copy the path.

You can also use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/) to download the vhd file easily.

Answer (score 0):

https://**storage-account-name**.blob.core.windows.net/**container-name**/**vhd-name**.vhd

You can also find the URL in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com). Open your storage account, go into the container and click the VHD you want. You will see "**URL**" in "**Blob properties**" blade.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/features/storage-explorer/).

Download, install, login and then browse to your container, select your .vhd and click download.