# Download Azure managed disk to local via powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

With the ability now to export a managed disk and download it locally via the portal, is there a way to do this via powershell?

Or do you still need to first copy it to a storage account and then pull it down?

As per this post:
[Download Azure VHD to local use powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114240/download-azure-vhd-to-local-use-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, the managed disk would not show the URL that you need to download from Azure through PowerShell, even if it is also just a VHD file. So you should first get the VHD file URL through copying it to a storage account blob. Then you can download it with the ways you want. I suggest the AzCopy that provide in your link.

Or you can just generate URL and then download it in the Azure Portal without copy it to a storage account first. Hope this will help.

Comment: OK thanks, seems a little redundant to have to copy it to a storage account/blob first. Especially considering I can download it directly from the portal.

Comment: Yes, because Azure manages it for you. And it can download it with the URL just known itself. It's the difference between the managed disk and unmanaged disk.

Comment: @amaru96 Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: does it incur any cost for the download?

Comment: @EvaCheong No, the download is free.

Comment: I think there is cost incurred for the download bandwidth as I got charged.

Comment: @EvaCheong As I know, it only costs for managing the disk, not downloading.