# Get azure disk info csv

Tags: azure, powershell

Hi I'm trying to get disk information alongside network information for azure virtual machines.

I'm probably doing something silly, but I thought it would be a case of adding the vm into the network foreach loop.

I've put the script below, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
$reportName = "sample.csv"
$report = @()
$vms = Get-AzVM

$publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null} 
foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
    $info = "" | Select VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirturalNetwork, Subnet, DnsServers, NicDns, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, OSDisk, DiagDisk, DataDisk, PublicIPAddress, vCPU, Memory
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
        if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
            $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
            } 
        } 

        #$location = $vm.location
        $info.OsType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType 
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name 
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
        $info.Region = $vm.Location 
        $info.VmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        $size = $info.VmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        $info.vCPU = (Get-AzVMSize -Location $location | ? {$_.name -eq $size}).NumberOfCores
        $info.Memory = (Get-AzVMSize -Location $location | ? {$_.name -eq $size}).MemoryInMB
        $info.VirturalNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
        $info.Subnet = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-1] 
        $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
        $vm = get-azvm | ? {$_.name -eq $vm}
        foreach ($vms in $vm) {
        $info.OSDiskSizeGB = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        $info.OSDisk = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.uri
        $info.DiagDisk = $vm.DiagnosticsProfile.BootDiagnostics.StorageUri
        $info.DataDisk = $vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.vhd.uri -join "**"
        }

        $report+=$info 
    } 
$report | ft VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirturalNetwork, Subnet, DnsServers, NicDns, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, OSDisk, DiagDisk, DataDisk, PublicIPAddress, vCPU, Memory 
$report | Export-CSV "c:\temp\$reportName"
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

This is the output I get, no disk infor for any VM

```
VmName    ResourceGroupName Region     VmSize         VirturalNetwork Subnet  DnsServers NicDns PrivateIpAddress  OsType OSDisk DiagDisk DataDisk PublicIPAddress vCPU Memory
------    ----------------- ------     ------         --------------- ------  ---------- ------ ----------------  ------ ------ -------- -------- --------------- ---- ------
vmr1-sec1 DEPLOYRG1         westeurope Standard_D2_v4 av-vnet         av-sub2                   172.0.2.4        Windows                                             2   8192
vmr2-sec1 DEPLOYRG1         westeurope Standard_D2_v4 av-vnet         av-sub2                   172.0.2.5        Windows                                             2   8192
cks-cp1   K8S               westeurope Standard_B2s   K8S-vnet        default                   10.0.0.4           Linux                          20.71.120.71       2   4096
```

Comment: What is the issue? Error message? Incorrect value?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hi Nick, I've added the table I get as an output *excuse the formatting( :)

Comment: Does `$info.OsType` have any data? What does `$vm.StorageProfile` look like if you view it in the console?

Comment: @NorrinRad Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Azure uses Azure managed disk in default.  Azure managed disks are no longer stored into blob storage by default. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3619/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-disk-and-un.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114240/download-azure-vhd-to-local-use-powershell).  if you want to get the vhd URL of Azure managed disk, you need to run the command `Grant-AzDiskAccess` to get it. **But please note that the URL has a life cycle and will expire after a period of time**

So I suggest you store your disk name or disk id in your CSV file